# QTcpSocket in a thread doesn't always send data instantly

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, tcp

I have a server which handles every client connection in a separate thread. To test it, I implemented a simple "echo" service: I type a message into a client, it is sent to the server, the server sends it back, and the client displays it.

As I only send short packets, I use only a single write and read for my current tests, I never had any split packets.

The client uses `write()` and `readAll()`, it works perfectly all the time (verified with a packet sniffer tool)

What I observe almost all the time, is that the server only sends packets at every second occasion.

For example:

- The client sends "abc"
- The server receives it, sends it back. The `write()` function returns 3.
- The client receives nothing. I check the packer sniffer, no packets were sent
- The client sends "def", several seconds, or even minutes later
- The server receives it, sends it back. The `write()` function returns 3.
- The client receives both the "abc" and "def" messages. 90% of the time as two separate packets, 10% of the time as "abcdef".

On very rare occasions, one message is enough. Most of the time, however, a second message is needed to send both the first and the second message.

An example of the client's debug output, indicating what was sent and received (note that everything the client sends is typed in manually, and between each message I waited at least 10 seconds):

```
Client: 1
Client: 2
Server: 1
Server: 2
Client: 12345
Server: 12345
Client: abc
Client: def
Server: abcdef
Client: 123
Server: 123
Client: 456
Client: 789
Server: 456789
Client: a
Server: a
Client: b
Client: c
Server: b
Server: c
```

I know that TCP is one continuous stream, but I wasn't expecting that on an unburdened LAN it should take minutes to transmit a few bytes. Interestingly, the client can send everything correctly and instantly, it never waits for further writes to glue them together.

As the client seems to work perfectly, I'm suspecting that something is wrong with my threads.

Once a `QTcpServer` receives an incoming connection, I start a new thread, passing the socketDescriptor to the thread's constructor.

```
TcpThread::TcpThread(int socketDescriptor, QObject *parent) : QThread(parent)
{
    this->socketDescriptor = socketDescriptor;
}

void TcpThread::run()
{
    if (!tcpSocket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)) {
        qDebug() << tcpSocket->error();
        return;
    }
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(read_data()));

    while (tcpSocket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
    {
        tcpSocket->waitForDisconnected(-1);
    }
}


void TcpThread::read_data()
{
    QByteArray data = tcpSocket->readAll();

    int nr = tcpSocket->write(data);
    qDebug() << data << " (" << nr << " bytes written)";
}
```

I know, this is not the [best practice](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) of handling threads, I just used the "Qt4 approach" for a quick familiarization with QTcpSocket.

What is interesting, is that I receive warnings at each call to `write()`:

> QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from
>   another thread

I wonder why. I created an instance of `QTcpSocket` in the `run()` method of my thread, so it should be in the same thread, shouldn't it?

Indeed, if I move the instantiation of the socket to the constructor, I get

> QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different
>   thread. (Parent is QTcpSocket(0x2c54a80), parent's thread is
>   QThread(0x10776d0), current thread is TcpThread(0x2c53c18)

which I didn't get before. However, even with the instantiation in the constructor, my code works exactly the same: the message is sometimes sent instantly, sometimes it is glued to and sent with the next message, no matter how much time passes between the two.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `TcpThread::read_data()` will not run in the same thread as `TcpThread::run()`. [*It is important to remember that a QThread instance lives in the old thread that instantiated it, not in the new thread that calls run(). This means that all of QThread's queued slots will execute in the old thread. Thus, a developer who wishes to invoke slots in the new thread must use the worker-object approach; new slots should not be implemented directly into a subclassed QThread.*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details)

Comment: @thuga ; I already knew that the constructor runs in the old thread, but as even that approach works sometimes, I expected that if there is a problem then no packets will be sent. I'll try the worker-object approach and I'll see if that helps.

Comment: I didn't mention constructor anywhere. I'm talking about your slot.

Comment: I know. I mentioned the constructor because that is also a case which runs in the old thread.

Comment: Yeah, but you still do stuff in the `TcpThread::run()` method. And `QTcpSocket` isn't a thread-safe class, so using the same instance in different threads will result in something unwanted happening.

Comment: Something you should also note is, that even if you decide to use a worker-object,  your `while` loop combined with `tcpSocket->waitForDisconnected(-1);` will block the event loop of that thread. So no slots will ever get called during that time.

Comment: "I have a server which handles every client connection in a separate thread." Well, for starters you shouldn't have a server that does that! It's a thoroughly stupid idea.

Comment: @KubaOber : What if the number of client connections is known to be less than 10, but the processing of the data of each client is very expensive? You know, there are many different scenarios an application can be designed for. Of course, in case of an instant messaging client with a large number of connections but almost no computation needed, if would indeed be a stupid idea. But what if there is a lot of number-crunching, video decoding, pattern recognition or other similar intensive work to do on a small number of connections?

Answer (score 1):

Using a thread with `QTcpSocket` s pointless. It is asynchronous API so gain from using thread is minimal (problem may be only when you are have other time consuming job which blocks event loop).

Another problem is the way you are creating objects and assign them to threads. You've given a perfect link about this topic but you completely didn't understand it.

Simple rules when using threads in QT:

- never assign thread to itself
- you can move objects between threads only if they don't have a parent (it they are root of memory structure tree, whole three is moved to new thread)
- setting a parent assigns object to parent thread
- default connections of slots and signals detects that signal was emitted from different thread the receiver is assigned to, so in such case signal is wrapped and passed to proper thread using its event loop.
- if you are using value objects in signal slots you don't need extra synchronization (locks and mutexes)
- when you override `QThread::run()` and using signals and slots you should run event loop in that thread, either by calling `QThread::exec()` or by creating new event loop.

So in general you have lots of mistakes in your code. I would recomand to abandon `QThread` or at least read that article again understand it and apply its recommendations (it was written before Qt5 was released, so your claim "Qt4 style" is invalid).

Comment: I know that I can use QTcpSocket asynchronously, I just wanted to use threads because the amount of data can be very large and the evaluation of the data can be extremely expensive. Therefore I wanted to have a try with the communication and its evaluation in a thread. Of course, not using threads for the communication itself, and using threads only for the evaluation of the data might also prove to be a good choice...

Comment: @vsz it doesn't matter, how much data are passed. Because callback is called after data received. You still may process data in another thread. Most expencive operation is creating a `QByteArray` that a `read` method will do. It's just memory allocation + copying.

Comment: `QTSPSocket` sends you data in chunks (you do not have control of size of this chunk), so you still processing very small chunks of data I don't thing so that processing this chunks will be so time consuming! Another advantage doing this without threads is that you will do this properly and later moving ready solution to thread will be just couple lines.